# incorporating foreign words with articles?

Tags: indefinite-article

I am helping with a Japanese tutorial and would like to omit indefinite (sometimes definite) articles when referencing a Japanese word.  Is this wise?  Can't seem to find info on this point.

Thanks

Comment: We would need an example.

Answer (score 3):

English nouns employ the article variously. Whilst you can say 'the flour', or 'some flour', you cannot say 'a flour', unless one is referring to a type of flour. Who is to use your tutorial- Japanese  students of English, or English students of Japanese? If the former I would have thought it important to keep them aware of the need for correct use of articles.